# Website Setup On Azure VM

Tags: azure, iis

I've been running the free trial and am trying to point of my name cheap domain to the vm web site I have created.

[image]

I covered the server Ip.

Here are my namecheap settings for the domain.
The covered Ip is the same as above..
[image]
Here are my IIS settings [image]
Change the Hostname to my actual domain.

I've also disabled Windows firewall and added port 80 and 443 in the security app hooked to the Azure VM. I can't seem to connect to the website at all. Am I missing something? I've been troubleshooting for hours and cant find anything except basic tutorials and how to do it on the Classic Azure portal.

thank you.

Comment: Instead of changing anything in the IIS settings, a quick and easy way is to go to your domain provider's admin panel (GoDaddy or wherever you purchased it from) and point the DNS server to VM's public IP address (the one which you have striked at very first place in the snip)

Comment: OK, I'll try that tomorrow. I thought I was doing that by the 'A' record / CNAME

Answer (score 0):

If you are using V1 (old portal/classic) Azure VM resources, then you need to open up the endpoint on the cloud services.  All VMs exist as part of a Cloud Service.
From the new portal,

- Select the VM (Classic)
- Settings
- Endpoints
- Add the required port (make sure public port is the one you want to use, say 80, and the internal port is the one IIS is listening for)

If you are using V2 resources, you need to add a public IP to your VM before it can be reached from the outside world.

From the new portal

- Click on the VM
- Open settings
- Select Network Interfaces
- Select IP Address
- Enable public IP (and add a PIP)

Keep in mind that in Azure, all IPs are dynamic.  You will want to configure DNS settings against the DNS names provided, and not the IP address (as this will change if you power off the machine).  For V1, use the cloud service name.  For V2, you are given the option when creating the PIP to have azure assign a DNS name.

For testing, try to telnet on port 80 to the correct DNS name.

Comment: Ok, On my VM page it says my public IP is 104.214.31.174 and my DNS name is osrs.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com....... but for whatever reason I still cannot reach it through the domain?

Comment: Yes port 80 and 443. I just set the cname to the domain at my registrar to the ors.southcentral address right?

Comment: Yes, you would just use a CNAME redirect pointed at the DNS name provided by Azure (osrs....)

Comment: Hmm OK, that's what I have. Maybe it just needs time to take affect ? Otherwise I have it setup exactly like all online tutorials say...frustrating

Comment: When I try and hit your webpage, I don't get access via the IP address or the DNS name.  Something is still blocking the connection.  Do you have Network Security Groups enabled?

Comment: This is the inbound rules i have. http://imgur.com/qSQFAXT  and i have windows firewall on the VM turned off...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100331/discussion-between-ctrldot-and-dylan).